# Solution of non-homogeneous ODE is always bounded

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I've been struggling with the following question:

$\ddot x + 2 \dot x +(1+e^{-t})x=t^{2}cos(t)$, show that all solution are bounded for $t>0$.

**My problem:** Im probably missing some theorem or fact. If we had, for example $\ddot x + 2 \dot x +(1+e^{-t})x=0$. Well that would be pretty easy to prove that all solutions tend to $0$ when $t$ tends to $\infty$. We only have to use a very well known theorem of perturbed systems. But for that one I cant find any theorem or anything that would help me to solve it.

Thanks so much. :)

Comment: Intuitively I would expect solutions to approach solutions to a linear inhomogeneous ODE with constant coefficients: $$x’’+2x’+x=t^2\cos(t)$$

Comment: However, solutions to the above do not seem to be bounded since the forcing function is unbounded.

Comment: What if you try using your well known theorem to prove that all solutions are _unbounded_.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! The theorem I can use for the homogeneous can only be used for homogeneous perturbed systems :/

Comment: The solution appears to grow like $t^2/2$. Are you really sure the solution is bounded?

Comment: Your observation on the homogeneous case means either all solutions to the inhomogeneous case are bounded, or all are unbounded. Now if you assume a particular solution is bounded then you can write the inhomogeneous as a linear ode with constant coefficients and forcing function that is exponentially close to $t^2 \cos(t)$.

Comment: Yeah! I solved it, it was pretty much applying the Duhamel formula and notice that since the homogeneous system was asymptotically stable the propagator is always bounded for $Ce^{-(t-t_{0})\alpha}$, where $0<\alpha<1$. Thanks so much anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the homogeneous, transforming Laplace we have

$$
(s+1)^2X_h(s) + X_h(s+1) = x_0s+x'_0
$$

or

$$
X_h(s) + \frac{X_h(s+1)}{(s+1)^2}=\frac{x_0s+x'_0}{(s+1)^2}
$$

now if ${\cal{L}}^{-1}[X_h(s)]$ is bounded then ${\cal{L}}^{-1}[X_h(s+1)]$ is also bounded due to pole translation. The final value condition establishes that

$$
\lim_{s\to 0}s\left(X_h(s)+\frac{X_h(s+1)}{(s+1)^2}\right)= \lim_{s\to 0}s\frac{x_0s+x'_0}{(s+1)^2}= 0
$$

Regarding the complete DE we have

$$
X(s) + \frac{X(s+1)}{(s+1)^2}=\frac{x_0s+x'_0}{(s+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}\frac{2s(s^2-3)}{(s^2+1)^3}
$$

which is unbounded because $\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}\frac{2s(s^2-3)}{(s^2+1)^3}$ is unbounded.

NOTE

If $X(s+1)$ is bounded then $\frac{X(s+1)}{(s+1)^2}$ is also bounded because $|f * g | \le |f||g|$